# Weird result from html2canvas

Tags: html2canvas

Im using HTML2Canvas to generate an image of a dashboard for an email.
The image I generate looks like this.[image]

where it should look like this.
[image]

Im not sure what to even look for to figure out the cause.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: html2canvas does not takes the actual screenshot. 
I am quoting a line of the official website



_It is only able to render correctly properties **that it understands**, meaning there are many CSS properties which do not work._
[List of supported Properties](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/features/).